# Corda Error during node deployment

Tags: java, gradle, corda

After I ./gradlew deployNodes, I get this error, any clue as to why this is happening?

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':java-source'.
Could not find method jcent∫er() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.
```

This is what I have in my gradle buildscript, and I believe I am checked out the release 13, but am not sure where to check.

```
ext.corda_release_version = '0.13.0'
    ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '0.12.4'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2'
    ext.quasar_version = '0.7.6'
    ext.junit_version = '4.12'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as if a spurious character has been added to `jcent∫er()`. Can you do a quick search ?